# Migrating from internal to external modules in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I've started working on a project where front-end part is written in Typescript and using AngularJS 1.x. Project is quite big - ~500 typescript files scattered all over the place in a solution of 92 C#/ASP.NET MVC projects.

All of the Typescript code is implemented using internal Typescript modules:

```
/// <reference path="../folder1/file1.ts" />
/// <reference path="../folder2/file2.ts" />

module Product.Module1 {
   export class Class1 {
      // ...
   }
}
```

The ultimate goal is migrating to Angular 2. It might be a wrong assumption but first step in migration path would be refactoring current Typescript code base from internal modules to external modules.

As you might imagine in a 500 file based Typescript application there is quite huge a dependency graph. Trying to convert the above sample to

```
class Class1 {
   // ...
}

export { Class1 };
```

raises a domino effect where internal modules depending on this file do not see `Class1` anymore. Doing `import { Class1 } from './samplefile'` in dependent modules makes situation even worse as now internal modules depending on them loose sense of their dependencies.

**My questions are:**
 - is there a way in migrating from internal modules to external modules
   in a step by step fashion?
 - maybe refactoring to external modules can be skipped? Then I do not see how Angular 1.x and Angular 2.x based application parts could share same code/types.

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out a migration strategy?

Comment: Working on it at the moment. Will have to present the strategy to my team and will post the answer here along the way. Hope will have time for this next week

Comment: Oh, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you reached out to the people that run the TypeScript project/found any useful post?

Comment: I work in a big company but there were no one who could give any clues. From the day I asked this question I've put this problem aside in hopes that someone from SO community will have some guidance for me. Unfortunately. Now that I have been given time specifically to solve this issue some trials and errors have actually led to good results (several converted modules in production already)